# Can (should) JavaScript promises be used for co-dependent functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Promises are great for attaching something to the *end* of an async call, without the async call needing to be aware of its followers. Can promises be used in more general or complex situations where callbacks are needed in the middle of an async call, and if so can it provide the same level of separation?

For example, suppose you have two functions a & b where the execution order transfers from a to b and back twice.

Using callbacks:

```
function a() {
    console.log('a1');
    b(function(b2) { 
        requestAnimationFrame(function() { 
            console.log('a2'); 
            b2(); 
        }); 
    });
}

function b(a2) {
    console.log('b1');
    a2(function() { 
        requestAnimationFrame(function() { 
            console.log('b2'); 
        }); 
    });
}
```

[image: this is something]

I'm aware that the two functions could be each broken into two pieces and strung together with promises, but that might lose important expensive-to-compute scope variables setup in a1/b1, or lead to redundant code or even harder to follow execution order.

The question is, can this code be rewritten using promises in such a way that b() doesn't need to know about a(), but does offer the caller a chance to interject something *before* b() is done executing?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following what you're trying to add to `b()` to give it more flexibility without knowing about `a()`.  Can you show an example of how you'd manually add that flexibility without promises?

Comment: This can be achieved wheter using callbacks or promises. If you want `a` and `b` to be decoupled from each other then use a process manager which will coordinate the entire process.

Comment: This can be achieved using "trampolines" which are more or less promises in a different guise - a function (wherever it comes from) acts as the "continue" action.

Comment: I'd just like to strengthen @jfriend00's comment above - I don't buy into the "callbacks are more tightly coupled" bull either. Promises are about providing a DSL to make flow control easier - having a method take a callback sometimes is not somehow magically tightly coupled - it's just a different form of flow control. Promises are more elegant often and are nicer to aggregate but that's it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think he means that `a` should not know about `b` and `b` should not know about `a`, but still being able to perform the process and hook at every step. If that's the case, then a simple process manager will do it. Anyway, that's what I understand from the question, but I could be wrong. It's not clear.

Comment: @plalx if only we had something that functions could do that'd let us perform actions before they finished but while they're executing. If only functions could yield control to other functions. Oh wait - we have that and it's called generators :D It's even the example here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisecoroutinegeneratorfunction-generatorfunction---function only here it's aware of the function - something that does what promise.coroutine does only with an hook at every phase would do it cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this is good stuff. Sorry my question isn't clear. I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: @jfriend00 If execution is limited to a->b->a, promises let me define b without taking a callback as input. I'm wondering if promises can be used to achieve the same (perhaps minor) benefit in the more complicated example I gave.

Comment: @user2864740 Researching trampolines, I haven't seen that term before, thanks!

Comment: @plalx You are understanding the question correctly, thanks! Will look at process management. Any recommends?

Comment: Are you trying to time slice the execution of two functions so that they take turns using the CPU while both executing?  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Your point is well taken, promises aren't magical, and there may be nothing wrong with using callbacks. IMO there's more value in having a common pattern for callbacks than in the mechanism. It's nice that it sometimes provides some decoupling, but its nicer that I can understand other people's control flow in less time. What I hoped to get out of this is whether my example fits a common pattern with a common name, as much as whether promises will help. And you're right, yield, with or without promises could probably get me there. Unfortunately, I can't run with ES6 yet...

Comment: @jfriend00 Taking turns isn't my goal, but it is a constraint I have. The example comes from an undo feature; a() is a view/controller method, and b() is a model method. Both have async parts that need to happen in a certain order. The user initiates a() and the ui is locked, but b() determines whether execution will proceed and if any state changes are allowed, then a() spends time redrawing, then b() commits state changes, then a() unlocks the ui. I'm wondering if promises provide a pattern that handles this case or not - can they be used here to provide the same benefits they normally do?

Comment: I'd suggest you break the different steps into their own functions.  If there is a lot of shared and temporary data, then create an object, put the data in the object and make each of the steps be methods on the object so that all the steps have easy access to all the data.  Then, you can simply sequence the steps with normal function calls or with promises (if a step is async).  You make the methods as small or granular as needed to allow you to interweave other things as needed.  This keeps the code of each step independent of the other operations and then you sequence things separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering, I've modified your example slightly to highlight execution flow:

```
function a() {
    console.log('a1');
    var c = function(b2) { 
        var d = function() { 
            console.log('a2'); 
            b2(); 
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(d);
    }
    b(c);
}

function b(a2) {
    console.log('b1');
    var e = function() { 
        var f = function() { 
            console.log('b2'); 
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(f);
    }
    a2(e);
}
```

This is the same code, except I've named the four anonymous functions `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`, because I want to refer to them.

Here's the order of execution:

1. `a` is called
2. `a` calls `b` synchronously
3. `b` calls `c` synchronously
4. `c` calls `requestAnimationFrame` (an async API)
5. `requestAnimationFrame` returns
6. `c` returns
7. `b` returns and is done executing
8. `a` returns and is done executing.

Later, when an animation frame becomes available, this happens:

9. `d` is called
10. `d` calls `e` synchronously
11. `e` calls `requestAnimationFrame`
12. etc.

Of course `e` has access to variables defined in `b` which outlive the execution of the original `b` thanks to JavaScript closures.

Likewise, in JavaScript, we view `a` as an asynchronous operation that ends once everything `a` initiates is done, but there are only two asynchronous steps (4 and 11) in it, so those two would benefit from promises.

Now onto your question: Can promises provide the same result and separation, without b knowing about a? Yes, but it wont be a fair comparison to your example, because it'll bulk up your synchronous calls to be asynchronous when it's unneeded:

```
function a() {
    console.log('a1');
    var b2;
    b().then(function(result) {
        b2 = result;
        return new Promise(function(r) { requestAnimationFrame(r); })
    }).then(function() { 
        console.log('a2'); 
        return b2();
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message); // error-handling
    });
}

function b() {
    console.log('b1');
    return Promise.resolve(function() {
        return new Promise(function(r) {
            requestAnimationFrame(r);
        }).then(function() { 
            console.log('b2'); 
        });
    });
}
```

The trick here is that b returns steps to execute later in a, which is a pattern that can be repeated.

Is this a good pattern? Hard to say without knowing more about the original use-case. For asynchronous calls I have yet to meet one that didn't benefit from promises, but for synchronous calls I wouldn't, since it alters execution order (unless maybe there's just one outlier and all the rest are asynchronous, and it helps readability).

Comment: Your analysis is good! You are answering my question, returning a promise within a promise is the solution that uses promises. Your answer would be better without the opener and without reference to the advice in comments. The opener is drawing a hard line that doesn't exist- what I mean by calling back into a is access to a's scope, which you clearly know. Mention of threads is out of place. a & b do not end "forever" at step 8, because their scopes live on. I don't mind the opinion, but the advice in comments ended by repeating what I stated in the question and said I wasn't asking about.

Comment: I made the preamble of a() and b() synchronous only to keep the code as short as possible, not intended to bound the scope and extent of my question so literally. My fault not yours. I put requestAnimationFrame in to force *some* asynchrony. What happens to your answer if the preamble to a() and b(), the synchronous parts, are made asynchronous also? Remove the possibility of callbacks, is using promises alone reasonable? What if the chain gets longer?

Comment: Thanks for helping me see that the hard line does not exist. I've edited my answer based on your feedback. I still have the opener to disclose the synchronous steps, as it bears on the answer I think, but I'm open to other ways. The pattern of returning steps for insertion later should be repeatable no matter the length of the chain.

Comment: Awesome, accepted. I guess I could have asked if promises can do something like promise.before( <code that runs before the promise executes> ). Its becoming clearer why this isn't a great idea, but that's how I was thinking of this problem - assuming a promise is guaranteed to be async, can I insert something in front of it rather than behind it? Promise within a promise works here, but it still imposes a burden on the caller to know what's inside the result, it doesn't provide the clean separation .then() normally does.

Comment: It's up to the function that returns a promise when to resolve it, so you'd have to talk to that function, not the promise. By the time you receive a promise from a function, it may in fact have already been resolved - which is the case with the promise returned from b() - making inserting something before it impossible. It's the .then() functions that are guaranteed to be asynchronous. e.g. p.then(x); y(); will never call x before y. Lastly, to clarify: the asynchronous result from b() that's assigned to b2 is a function, not a promise. It just returns a promise like all the other steps.